# How to use external Login OpenID provider in Asp.Net Core API web app?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, openid-connect

My question is how to use an external login (OpenID) provider apart from (google, facebook and known providers...) I have another external provider, but i don't know how to add it in startup.cs, can anyone give me an example on how to configure external login ? Thank you.

I tried to follow the same flow of google, but it's quite different.

Comment: Hi @Hamid Elouardaoui, For how to configure OpenID provider in asp.net core, you could check [this doc](https://github.com/onelogin/openid-connect-dotnet-core-sample).

Comment: @Rena thanks, that doc gave me at least an Idea. I hope it will work, I really appreciate it !